# Highlight multiple selected value in the option using ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm currently working on multiple select option, I have question regarding how to highlight the value from database. I have setState **getting the store type of the store**

**Output Should be like this**

[image: Ouput]

**The response of my api store type**
[image: Response API]

```
componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios.get('/api/get_update_store_data/'+ id).then(response => {
        this.setState({

            store_type:response.data[0].store_type,

        })
    }).catch(error => console.log(error.response));
}
```

I have the handle

```
handleStoreType(e){
    var options = e.target.options;
    var value = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            value.push(options[i].value);
        }
    }
    this.setState({store_type: value});
}
```

JSX File

```
<label>Store Type</label>
<select onChange={this.handleStoreType} value={this.state.store_type} multiple name="selectedOption" required="" className="form-control">
    <option selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="Dine-in">Dine-in</option>
    <option value="Take-out">Take-out</option>
    <option value="Home Delivery">Home Delivery</option>
    <option value="Drive Thru">Drive Thru</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please console.log() `response.data[0].store_type` in `componentDidMount()` and share the output. `store_type` needs to be an array with string values that match the `value` properties of the `<option>` exactly. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xeartt)

Comment: Output is Dine-in and Take-out

Comment: You are absolutely sure it's an array of strings that match the values of the `<option>`? The exact value `response.data[0].store_type` is `['Dine-in', 'Take-out']`? If it isn't, it won't highlight/select.

Comment: yes its array string

Comment: no its not, how to make the state look like that

Comment: Please update your question, not in the comments, what `response.data[0].store_type` inside the `then()` of the API call looks like **exactly** when it's `console.log(response.data[0].store_type)`.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderStaroselsky the result that i log it look like this. Dine-in,Take-out,Home Delivery,Drive Thru

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you shared, `response.data[0].store_type` is coming from the server as a string rather than an array of strings. It needs to be an array of string values matching the `value` property of the `<option>` elements in your `<select>` exactly. Try the following using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to turn the string into an array of strings, splitting on the comma character:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const id = this.props.match.params.id;

  axios.get('/api/get_update_store_data/'+ id)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        store_type: response.data[0].store_type.split(',')
      })
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Glad to help! Hopefully that make sense what the issue was. Happy coding! be sure to mark the answer if resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it in your JSX/HTML:

```
<option value="Dine-in"><mark>Dine-in</mark></option>
<!-- Other options -->
<option value="Drive Thru"><mark>Drive Thru</mark></option>
```